# How to disable or replace X-Powered-By header in Sails.js application

Tags: javascript, express, http-headers, sails.js

When I run Sails.js application, it adds the following HTTP header automatically to every response: `X-Powered-By: "Sails <sailsjs.org>"`.

Is it possible to disable or override it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's quite possible.

You will need to disable the Sails's middleware called `poweredBy` and also tell Express.js server not to add it's own header.

Just update your `config/http.js` configuration file to looks like this:

```
module.exports.http = {
  middleware: {

    disablePoweredBy: function(request, response, next) {
      var expressApp = sails.hooks.http.app;
      expressApp.disable('x-powered-by');
//    response.set('X-Powered-By', 'One Thousand Hamsters');
      next();
    },

    order: [
//    ...
//    'poweredBy',
      'disablePoweredBy',
//    ...
    ]
  }
};
```

Here, we are retrieving an instance of [Express Application](http://expressjs.com/api.html#application) from Sails hooks and then using it's [`disable()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.disable) method to set the `x-powered-by` configuration parameter to `false` value. That will prevent the header from appearing.

And in order to enable this custom middleware, you will need to add it to the `order` array. You can just replace `poweredBy` middleware with `disablePoweredBy`.

Also, by un-commenting the `response.set()` method you can set your own header value.

Comment: As of at least 2016 (maybe even earlier), you don't need to disable Express' X-Powered-By, as Sails already does this, even if you disable Sails' poweredBy.

Answer (score 12):

Edit your `config/http.js` and set `poweredBy` to `false`:

```
module.exports.http = {
  middleware: {
    poweredBy: false
  }
}
```

Since [Sails will disable](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/e85810a8ff1f5a62f890bcaadd6a63c6ca6f98b4/lib/hooks/http/initialize.js#L57) the express X-Powered-By header there is no need to disable it manually.

Comment: This works perfectly with sails v 0.12. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: This also works well with v1.5.3.

Answer (score 2):

No need to create a new middleware, You can over ride the poweredBy middleware of Sails.js, for example

```
module.exports.http = {
  middleware: {
    poweredBy:  function (req, res, next) {
      // or uncomment if you want to replace with your own
      // res.set('X-Powered-By', "Some Great Company");      
      return next();
    }
  }
}
```